# Can I read files inside a directory without using OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, xbap

I have an app and I am thinking that a WPF XBAP app would be best suited for this. However, I am not aware of the limitations that it comes with. So, before choosing this tool I need to be aware of it.

Basically I want to read any folder inside the OS and get listing of files inside that folder. Is this possible using WPF XBAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpenFileDialog` is just a media that makes `selection` & `reading` easier. You can read any `folder` as long as you know `path` & `have permission` to read the folder.